# How to use SCAN with the MATCH option in Predis

Tags: php, redis, predis

I have previously used the [`KEYS`](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command to search for keys matching a certain pattern in my Redis database. Since Redis 2.8, the [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command seems to be preferred over `KEYS` since it returns an iterator instead of scanning through the whole keyspace at once.

I'm using [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) >= 0.8.5 which is supposed to support PHP iterators for the `SCAN` command. Predis doesn't have a lot of documentation, so I'm wondering how to translate the following `KEYS` command to it's `SCAN` counterpart:

```
$client->keys($pattern)
```

I have tried the following:

```
$client->scan('MATCH', $pattern);
```

Which kind of works - but it doesn't return a native PHP iterator. It would be really nice to use Predis' built-in iterator support.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found how to do it in the [Predis examples directory](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.0/examples/redis_collections_iterators.php).

To use `SCAN` to search for matching keys in a database, you simply use the `Predis\Collection\Iterator\Keyspace` class:

```
use Predis\Collection\Iterator;

$client = ...;
$pattern = 'foo*';

foreach (new Iterator\Keyspace($client, $pattern) as $key) {
    ...
}
```

Apparently Predis has an iterator class in `Predis\Collection\Iterator` for each of the commands that return iterators:

- `Keyspace` for [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/scan)
- `HashKey` for [`HSCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/hscan)
- `SetKey` for [`SSCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/sscan)
- `SortedSetKey` for [`ZSCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/zscan)
- `ListKey` for [`LRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) - This doesn't really use Redis iterators, but it's a nice interface to `LRANGE` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful for other Predis beginners and you're coming from a PHP/MySQL background like me you can use this:

```
foreach (new Iterator\HashKey($client, $pattern) as $index => $value) {
    ...
}
```

When you previously generated an array dataset with `$client->hmset($index, $array)`.