# Infinite loop when using predis SCAN

Tags: redis, predis

I'm trying to replace the keys function from predis for scan in order to increase the performance in some parsing that we do.

The problem is that when I do the scan operation it seems to fall into an infinite loop, which makes no sense because according to the redis documentation scan will return the iterator to 0 when it's done.

```
        $it = null;
        $keysFound = [];

        do {

            $redisKeys = $redis->scan($it,"*{$query}", 10);

            if (!empty($keys)) {
                array_merge($keysFound, $redisKeys);
            }
        } while($it != 0);
```

I just want to replace it so we don't do this

```
$keys = $redis->keys("*{$query}");
```

I have tried everything, please some help.

UPDATE
Checking on the cli I see that it never finds the key and stays in loop even if I put the exact same key that I can see in redsmin.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 122880 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "118784"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 118784 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "18432"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 18432 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "59392"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 59392 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "63488"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 63488 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "123904"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 123904 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "19456"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 19456 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "121856"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 121856 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "115200"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 115200 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "119296"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> scan 119296 MATCH x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 
1) "109056"
2) (empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Is there something that could be wrongly configured? I have never worked with redis before so I don't know if it could be wrong configuration related.

SOLVED
The issue was that we have a very big amount of keys so increasing the COUNT value to a bigger amount gave the correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the scan yourself, then you need to capture the returned cursor from the response:

```
$it = null;
$keysFound = [];

do {

    $response = $redis->scan($it,"*{$query}", 10);

    $it = $response[0];
    $redisKeys = $response[1];

    if (!empty($keys)) {
        array_merge($keysFound, $redisKeys);
    }
} while($it != 0);
```

See https://redis.io/commands/scan to understand the response.

But take a look at the iterators, as you may be reinventing the wheel (taken from [How to use SCAN with the MATCH option in Predis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545549/how-to-use-scan-with-the-match-option-in-predis), added `count`):

```
use Predis\Collection\Iterator;

$client = ...;
$pattern = 'foo*';
$count = 100;

foreach (new Iterator\Keyspace($client, $pattern, $count) as $key) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried the first option but I still get empty results while keys returns me content, any other ideas?

Comment: It is OK to get no keys in some of the few scan calls. Have you tried the scan command on redis-cli to troubleshoot what could be wrong? You can the try MONITOR command on Redis-cli and run your php code, see if there is any difference

Comment: Hi LeoMurillo thanks for the reply, I tried the command redis-cli (I cant try MONITOR because the production is executing too many redis calls to be able to see something). I just updated the post if you could give it a look I'll be grateful.

Comment: x_dashboard_dashboard_row_1005_251 has no pattern-matching wild card, so only  one key from the whole space will be retrieved. For as long as you get a cursor, your scan is making progress. See [Redis `SCAN`: how to maintain a balance ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564896/redic-scan-how-to-maintain-a-balance-between-newcomming-keys-that-might-match/59569053#59569053), you can even calculate the percentage of progress based in the cursor